# How to get non-zero symbolic solution for a system of steady state ODEs in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, ode, symbolic-math

Below is the code I've written for MATLAB using the `solve` function to symbolically solve a system of linear ODEs for their steady state solutions. However, I can only get zero solutions (exact output at the end of this post).

```
syms c1 c2 o1 o2 %variables 
syms a1 a2 b1 b2 h1 h2 g1 g2 %parameters  

eq1 = -(a1 + g2)*c1 + b1*c2 + h1*o1 == 0; %steady state equations
eq2 = -(b1 + g1)*c2 + a1*c1 + h1*o2 == 0;
eq3 = -(a2 + h2)*o1 + g2*c1 + b2*o2 == 0;
eq4 = -(b2 + h1)*o2 + g1*c2 + a2*o1 == 0; 

sol = solve([eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4], [c1, c2, o1, o2]); 
%solve for steady state solutions 

sol1 = sol.c1
sol2 = sol.c2
sol3 = sol.o1
sol4 = sol.o2 
%display solutions
```

Here is the output from this:

```
>>> source("linsolve.m")
>>> sol1 = (sym) 0
>>> sol2 = (sym) 0
>>> sol3 = (sym) 0
>>> sol4 = (sym) 0
```

I have manually worked out the solutions for this system, and the solution above does not match it. What is going wrong?

Comment: How do you know that the solution is incomplete? What is the expected complete solution?

Comment: I have the solution that was worked out manually. It should look like this: https://imgur.com/a/RfwkM14